# Flexbox, смещение блоков при изменении ширины экрана

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, flexbox

```css
.facts{
  /* border: solid 1px silver; */
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  text-align: center;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
.fact{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  flex-shrink: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="facts">
    <div class="fact">
        <img src="udobstvo.png" width=10 height=90>

        <strong> Удобство </strong><br> <br>
        Держат ногу в одном положении,
        можно стирать в машинке,  можно быстро сушить
     </div>
     <div class="fact">
         <img src="vozduh.png" width=10 height=90>

         <b> Воздухопроницаемость </b><br> <br>
         Превосходные воздухопроницаемые
         отверстия для проветривания, что
         не даёт ногам ребенка запотеть
      </div>
      <div class="fact">
          <img src="obhvat.png" width=10 height=90>

          <b> Правильный обхват </b><br> <br>
          Свободное движение пальцев ног
           для улучшения когнитивного и моторного развития
       </div>
       <div class="fact">
       <img src="bezopasnost.png" width=10 height=90>

       <b> Безопасность </b><br> <br>
       В производстве не используются опасные материалы, такие как:
       клей и формальдегид
    </div>
    <div class="fact">
    <img src="gibkost.png" width=100 height=90>

    <b> Легкие и гибкие </b><br> <br>
    По весу, почти не отличаются от носков
 </div>
          </div>
```

При уменьшении надо, чтобы те блоки, которые не помещаются, смещались вниз, но при нормальных размерах, стояли как надо.
И чтобы все были одного размера и не растягивались на всю страницу.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

В классе **fact** задай конкретную ширину, например: `width: 400px;`
В классе **facts** добавь: `flex-wrap: wrap;`